# How to fix this after firebase update?

Tags: firebase

### Heading

PS D:\Progetti\SitoWebLavoro> firebase deploy
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:936
throw err;
^

Error: Cannot find module 'semver'
Require stack:

- C:\Users\Fabio\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\bin\firebase.js
  at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
  at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
  at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
  at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
  at Object. (C:\Users\Fabio\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\bin\firebase.js:4:16)
  at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:14)
  at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:10)
  at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
  at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
  at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
  'C:\Users\Fabio\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\bin\firebase.js'
  ]
  }

---

Comment: This is the error message that the console gives me after I try to deploy the project ..

Comment: What command did you use to update Firebase?

Comment: unfortunately I don't remember the command but it was suggested in the vsc console, to update to the latest version .. and I copied and pasted the command

Comment: Well, it might be less time consuming to just uninstall npm completely (including its cache) and reinstall it than trying to figure this one out. But maybe someone else is able to help.

Comment: when i try to uninstall npm it gives me this error:
 npm uninstall
npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use `--location=global` instead.
npm ERR! Must provide a package name to remove

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Fabio\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-06-24T18_07_24_529Z-debug.log

Comment: thanks again, for your patience .. I feel stuck ..

Comment: I solved it by uninstalling the cache of npm and node .. reinitialized everything and goes .... thanks !!!